# Will contents of spark dataframe constructed out of java timestamps and written to parquet differ depending on the system's local timezone?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I've been having a good deal of trouble lately creating reliable unit tests for a spark application in Java that deals with timestamps.

Specifically, I'm having a hard time convincing myself that the code I'm testing will produce the same results regardless of the timezone of the system it is run on.

Take the following dummy test as an starting point:

```
public class TimestampsTest {

    @Test
    public void timestampsTest() {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSessionBuilder.getTestSparkSession();

        Timestamp timestamp1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-01 01:00:00");
        println("Timestamp 1:");
        println(timestamp1.toString());
        println("Instant 1:");
        println(timestamp1.toInstant().toString());
        Timestamp timestamp2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-01 02:00:00");
        println("Timestamp 2:");
        println(timestamp2.toString());
        println("Instant 2:");
        println(timestamp2.toInstant().toString());
        List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create(timestamp1),
                RowFactory.create(timestamp2)
        );
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
                Collections.singletonList(DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, false))
        );

        println("Spark dataframe:");
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
        df.show();
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Spark version:
2.4.3

Timestamp 1:
2019-01-01 01:00:00.0
Instant 1:
2019-01-01T06:00:00Z

Timestamp 2:
2019-01-01 02:00:00.0
Instant 2:
2019-01-01T07:00:00Z

Spark dataframe:
+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2019-01-01 01:00:00|
|2019-01-01 02:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

The timestamps in the dataframe match the text input that I used to create the original Java timestamps, but the underlying instants do not. (I'm running this in EST5EDT, so the Timestamp objects represent the times in EST5EDT, while the Instant objects are represented in UTC when converted to a string. This is all totally expected.)

My question is this:

Is spark constructing the dataframe using the runtime Java representation of the timestamp objects or is it using the UTC instants and then simply displaying them in EST5EDT when I call show() on the dataframe? Stated another way: Is there a deterministic relationship between the string representation of the timestamp in java and the contents of the dataframe *or* is there a deterministic relationship between the instants on the UTC timeline and the contents of the dataframe?

I know that the output of df.show() is going to be the same regardless of the timezone in which this code is run, given that both scenarios described above will result in the same output from show(). However, if I were to save the contents of the dataframe to parquet, would I end up with the same results regardless of which timezone my code is run in? In other words, if I save this dataframe to parquet and then read it into spark in another environment with a different local timezone, will the dataframe be identical? Or will it be the underlying UTC time that will be identical, meaning that the local representation would depend on which local timezone I'm running in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question by running some tests.

Timestamps in a spark dataframe written to parquet will not be the same if they are read into a dataframe on a machine in a different timezone. In other words, spark appears to save the value of the underlying instant on the UTC timeline to parquet and then display it in whatever local timezone is active on the system where it is read. The tests below demonstrate this to be the case:

A couple of helper functions that we'll need:

```
void printStats(SparkSession spark, Timestamp timestamp1, Timestamp timestamp2, Dataset<Row> df) {
    println("Spark version:");
    println(spark.version());
    println("");

    println("Timezone:");
    println(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));

    println("Timestamp 1:");
    println(timestamp1.toString());
    println("Instant 1:");
    println(timestamp1.toInstant().toString());
    println("");

    println("Timestamp 2:");
    println(timestamp2.toString());
    println("Instant 2:");
    println(timestamp2.toInstant().toString());
    println("");

    println("Spark dataframe:");
    df.show();
    println("");
}

Dataset<Row> createDataframe(SparkSession spark, Timestamp timestamp1, Timestamp timestamp2) {
    List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(timestamp1),
            RowFactory.create(timestamp2)
    );
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
            Collections.singletonList(DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, false))
    );

    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
}
```

First write some timestamps to parquet with the machine in EST:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSessionBuilder.getTestSparkSession();
Timestamp timestamp1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-01 01:00:00");
Timestamp timestamp2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-01-01 02:00:00");
Dataset<Row> df = createDataframe(spark, timestamp1, timestamp2);
printStats(spark, timestamp1, timestamp2, df);
String tempPath = "/temp/timestamps_test";
df.write().parquet(tempPath);
```

Console output:

```
Timezone:
America/New_York
Timestamp 1:
2019-01-01 01:00:00.0
Instant 1:
2019-01-01T06:00:00Z

Timestamp 2:
2019-01-01 02:00:00.0
Instant 2:
2019-01-01T07:00:00Z

Spark dataframe:
+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2019-01-01 01:00:00|
|2019-01-01 02:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Now, we switch the machine to UTC and read the timestamps back into a new dataframe:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSessionBuilder.getTestSparkSession();
String tempPath = "/temp/timestamps_test";
Dataset<Row> readDf = spark.read().parquet(tempPath);
Timestamp retrieved1 = (Timestamp) readDf.collectAsList().stream().map(r -> r.getTimestamp(0)).toArray()[0];
Timestamp retrieved2 = (Timestamp) readDf.collectAsList().stream().map(r -> r.getTimestamp(0)).toArray()[1];
printStats(spark, retrieved1, retrieved2, readDf);
```

Output:

```
Timezone:
UTC
Timestamp 1:
2019-01-01 06:00:00.0
Instant 1:
2019-01-01T06:00:00Z

Timestamp 2:
2019-01-01 07:00:00.0
Instant 2:
2019-01-01T07:00:00Z

Spark dataframe:
+-------------------+
|          timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2019-01-01 06:00:00|
|2019-01-01 07:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Note that the instants are identical regardless of the timezone, indicating that what is being stored in parquet is the UTC instant, not the local timestamp.